# При использовании Камеры приложение удаляется из памяти, как избежать этого?

Tags: java, android, камера, activity-life-cycle

Запускаю камеру

```
captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
captureIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedPhotoPath);
captureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(captureIntent, RESULT_CAMERA);
```

При первом запуске все Ок.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {...}
else {super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);}
```

onActivityResult отрабатывает как надо. При повторном обращении к камере и создании снимка, отрабатывает

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(MY_LOG, "onRestoreInstanceState");

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(MY_LOG, "onResume ");
}
```

Т.е. получается, что приложение перезапускается.

Не всегда, иногда получается обратиться к камере два раза, а на третий происходит перезапуск.

Как этого избежать? Как запретить системе выгружать из памяти приложение?